# Obtaining google email address using OAuth2.0 java spring

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make a Google login in my spring MVC application, but after the user is signed in, I can't find a way to get his email address. I was able to obtain his name and id from UserInfo, but that's all I can get.

This is my configuration file:

```
    @Bean
    // TODO retrieve from https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration ?
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails googleOAuth2Details() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails googleOAuth2Details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        googleOAuth2Details.setAuthenticationScheme(form);
        googleOAuth2Details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(form);
        googleOAuth2Details.setClientId(clientId);
        googleOAuth2Details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        googleOAuth2Details.setUserAuthorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
        googleOAuth2Details.setAccessTokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
        googleOAuth2Details.setScope(asList("openid"));
        return googleOAuth2Details;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection") // Provided by Spring Boot
    @Resource
    private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public OAuth2RestOperations googleOAuth2RestTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleOAuth2Details(), oAuth2ClientContext);
    }
```

Here is my authentication filter:

```
public class OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Resource
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    protected OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> authentication); // AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter requires an authentication manager.
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        final ResponseEntity<UserInfo> userInfoResponseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo", UserInfo.class);
        return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(userInfoResponseEntity.getBody(), empty(), NO_AUTHORITIES);
    }
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class SampleSecuredController {
        @Autowired UserService userService;
        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public String test(HttpServletRequest request) {
            UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userInfo.getId());
            System.out.println(userInfo.getName());
            System.out.println(userInfo.getLink());
        }
    }
```

UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final String givenName;
    private final String familyName;
    private final String gender;
    private final String picture;
    private final String link;

    @JsonCreator
    public UserInfo(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                    @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                    @JsonProperty("given_name") String givenName,
                    @JsonProperty("family_name") String familyName,
                    @JsonProperty("gender") String gender,
                    @JsonProperty("picture") String picture,
                    @JsonProperty("link") String link) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.link = link;
    }
    //getters and setters here
}
```

Comment: if your user authenticates with Oauth, you have his email... no? Using this API might help you here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/